# Data restructuring using R

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I have a dataset (dat) that looks like this:

```
 Person       IPaddress
36598035    222.999.22.99
36598035    222.999.22.99
36598035    222.999.22.99
36598035    222.999.22.99
36598035    222.999.22.99
36598035    444.666.44.66
37811171    111.88.111.88
37811171    111.88.111.88
37811171    111.88.111.88
37811171    111.88.111.88
37811171    111.88.111.88
```

It reflects instances of that individuals logged into a website over a certain period of time.  I need the data to look like this:

```
Person        IPaddress      Number of Logins
36598035    222.999.22.99           6
37811171    111.88.111.88           5
```

So, instead of multiple entries for the same person, there is just one row per individual, with a count of how many times they logged in.

Also, you'll notice in my example that person 36598035 logged in under more than 1 IP address.  When this happens, I want the IP address in the final dataset to reflect the mode IP address--in other words, the IP address that the individual logged in under most frequently.

Comment: @ waxattax: number of logins should be 5,5 and not 6,5

Comment: @rnso no, I think you're misinterpreting the question.

Comment: @mso Actually, person 36598035 did log in 6 times, just from 2 different IP addresses.  I would like to preserve the fact that the person logged in 6 times, regardless of which IP addresses s/he logged in from.  Thanks for your help!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
    group_by(Person, IPaddress) %>% # For each combination of person and IPaddress
    summarize(freq = n()) %>% # Get total number of log-in
    arrange(Person, desc(freq)) %>% # The most frequent IP address is in the 1st row for each user
    group_by(Person) %>% # For each user
    mutate(total = sum(freq)) %>% # Get total number of log-in
    select(-freq) %>% # Remove count
    do(head(.,1)) # Take the first row for each user

#    Person     IPaddress total
#1 36598035 222.999.22.99     6
#2 37811171 111.88.111.88     5
```

**UPDATE**

`dplyr` 0.3 is out now. So, you could do the following as well. Just one line shorter by using `count`. I also used `slice` as @aosmith recommended.

```
mydf %>%
    count(Person, IPaddress) %>%
    arrange(Person, desc(n)) %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(n)) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Comment: Have you explored `slice` yet?  You could use it in place of the `do` line (`slice(1)`).

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the note. I have seen a few users using `slice`. I will play with it now. Have you noticed any other changes in 0.3? I would like to know if any functions are deprecated in 0.3. @akrun kindly mentioned that `summarise_each_q` is deprecated. So is `mutate_each_q`.

Comment: There are a few other new things.  Just check out the NEWS for each version [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `data.table` for a concise solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, list(IPaddress=names(which.max(table(IPaddress))),
           Logins=.N), 
    by=Person]
```

Comment: This really is concise! I am learning data.table now. Thanks for sharing this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ddf
     Person     IPaddress
1  36598035 222.999.22.99
2  36598035 222.999.22.99
3  36598035 222.999.22.99
4  36598035 222.999.22.99
5  36598035 222.999.22.99
6  36598035 444.666.44.66
7  37811171 111.88.111.88
8  37811171 111.88.111.88
9  37811171 111.88.111.88
10 37811171 111.88.111.88
11 37811171 111.88.111.88

dd1 = data.table(with(ddf, table(Person, IPaddress)))[rev(order(N))][!duplicated(Person)]
dd1
     Person     IPaddress N
1: 36598035 222.999.22.99 5
2: 37811171 111.88.111.88 5

dd1$all_login_count = data.table(with(ddf, table(Person)))$V1
dd1
     Person     IPaddress N all_login_count
1: 36598035 222.999.22.99 5               6
2: 37811171 111.88.111.88 5               5
```

Comment: This omits the less-common IP address, which is not what the question asked for.

Comment: It shows what is asked: "the IP address that the individual logged in under most frequently."

Comment: The *count* should include *all* IP addresses. The IP address listed should be the most frequent. Look at the example in the post.

Comment: This would be right if you first "filled in" the IPs for each Person with the modal IP for that Person.

Comment: @mso I tried your solution, but obtained the following error message: `Error in table(Person, IPaddress): attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`